# Usage of word "treat" in context of "a party"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, subcontinental-english

Many times I hear people saying, "*we want a treat*" on the occasion of a person's birthday, for which they mean, "a birthday party".

I am concerned about the use of word "treat" in this context. Is this common with native English speakers or is it just another Indianism? Is it a colloquial usage of word "treat"?

Comment: "trick or treat"?  Look up treat and see what you find.

Comment: @Xanne it's "treat" and I am curious about its usage for the meaning of a "party".

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well, there are lots of kinds of treats--it's used much more broadly than a synonym for a party (meaning a social event), at least in AmE.

Comment: If someone asked for a *treat*, it wouldn't normally be taken to be a request for a *birthday party*. It has more the sense of a personal gift for whoever is receiving the treat.

Comment: So "we want a treat" here means: "we want you to host a party", not "we want you to give us something nice (to eat or drink)"?

Comment: @Stefan Now I am more confused. Aren't both same: "hosting a party" or "giving them something to eat/drink"?

Comment: I don’t think it is quite the same, but it might be a cultural thing, rather than a language thing. It also depends on the setting; at work I would perhaps be asked: you just had your birthday, why didn't you bring a cake ?(usually said in good humour, not demanding). My family/friends would perhaps ask, don't you want to celebrate by having a party? The former is a treat in the narrow sense, the latter is about hosting a party. But, there might be more than one meaning, I'm not sure.

Comment: @dheer The difference is that a *party* involves guests getting treats as well (cake, presents, etc), whereas giving *them* something to eat/drink has the *individual* receiving the treat. When someone asks for a treat, it's normally implied that the treat is for the individual. But certainly, there may be some overlap and regionalisms involved.

Comment: @Lawrence & Stefan: I got it. You can kindly put your comments as answers, or a single answer comprising of all comments. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you’re hearing is.

> *We wanna **treat***  (We want to treat)

This means because it’s your birthday we want to buy dinner, or the movie, or whatever  it is that they’re out doing.

***to treat*** (treat someone to)

> Provide someone with (food, drink, or entertainment) at one's own expense.
>   *‘he treated her to a slap-up lunch’*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/treat)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For it to be *immediately* obvious that "we want a treat" should be taken to mean "we want you (to throw/organise/host) a birthday party" suggests a highly marked context, one in which the speakers have, among themselves, developed the (slightly unusual?) habit of referring to birthday parties thus. But it's not that hard to imagine in the context of a microlect constructed and maintained by a group of acquaintances. I've personally been part of tight social groups in which the word "treat" has had very particular meanings understood by all members. I won't tell you what they were!